# Firebase - $requireAuth for every page - performances issue?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Hello guys,

I'm building an application with AngularFire. To be sure the user is identified and has access to the page he's asking for, I added a resolve with $requireAuth condition on an abstract state parenting all the "logged in" section of the app.

```
.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'views/app.html',
    controller: 'appCtrl',
    resolve: {
        // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
        // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
        "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
            // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
            // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
            return Auth.$requireAuth();
        }]
    }
})
```

This is the intended use, as stated here : https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-requireauth

My simple question : isn't this a bit of a performance issue, since on every new page the user has to wait for Firebase to answer the request about his current login status ?

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is commonly used to build so-called Single Page Applications. In such an application the user navigates from view to view within a single page. In such a scenario, Firebase will maintain the authentication state between views and the promise will resolve immediately.

Hint: check the network tab of your browser's developer tools to see the traffic.

Comment: I thought about something like this, but you simply did a great job at making it crystal clear :) Thank you !